# FTPS in Spring or Applet

Tags: spring, file-upload, applet, sftp, ftps

I have a requirement to provide Secure-File-Upload file feature as a new service in my existing application. Expected Upload file size would be huge like over 100MB. If I do plugin-in such feature into my application it will surely die. 
At the same time I need to provide or launch that service only through my current application, anyhow I need to achieve it without affecting my current application at any cost.

I am thinking of two solutions in mind, request others advise

1. Develop a small file uploader web app, host it in a seperate web/app severs,
   launch it from my current application through some link. (I can not ask user to login into another new url)
2. Render an Applet to achieve secure file transfer service (in this point I am not clear whether the applet can directly talk to SFTP server without hindering
   my current app's server components)

Further, I am referring to Spring Integration docs with FTP server.
I wonder Can a spring controller receive stream from client via FTPS connection and immediately transfer to FTP server without having to store it in local file.

Please advise your views. 
Thanks&Regards,
Sabari

Comment: Why would it die? Why would you need an SFTP (or FTPS) for that? Why wouldn't a simply file-upload over HTTPS not suffice? There are plenty of samples out-there explaining how to do large file transfer over HTTP.

Comment: Thanks for the indication Deinum, I was under an assumption that FTP is faster and reliable than HTTP for large file transfer. Went through some comparison data, realized no major advantage to use FTP/FTPS now rethinking to go ahead with HTTPS. https://daniel.haxx.se/docs/ftp-vs-http.html  http://www.isi.edu/lsam/publications/http-perf/